# When router has a parameter, then component can't find index.html's style

Tags: angular, parameters, router

angular 2.0.0-rc.4

When router has a parameter `localhost:4200/component/parameter` then I get an error message like this `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:4200/(component name here)/style.css`

Have no idea why in this case it automatically adds component name. style.css is in global directory with index.html

import style.css in index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

my routes

```
import { provideRouter, RouterConfig } from '@angular/router';
import { HomepageComponent } from './homepage/homepage.component';
import { LoginpageComponent } from './loginpage/loginpage.component';
import { RegisterpageComponent } from './registerpage/registerpage.component';
import { PostpageComponent } from './postpage/postpage.component';
import { TestComponent } from './test/test.component';

const routes: RouterConfig = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'homepage',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  { path: 'homepage', component: HomepageComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginpageComponent },
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterpageComponent },
  { path: 'test/:text', component: TestComponent },
  { path: 'post/:id', component: PostpageComponent }
];

export const routerProviders = [
  provideRouter(routes)
];
```

So style.css is here -> `http://localhost:4200/style.css`

When I go to `http://localhost:4200/test/sometext` then I get an error that it cannot find style.css inside `http://localhost:4200/test/style.css`

I checked that if there is no parameter, then all works good.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This isn't even related to Angular. Your issue come from the relative and absolute paths notation. The path you provide in your link tag is "style.css", which is a relative path, so your browser will take the current url path and look for your file there. To make it work just put your href attribute in absolute :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css">
```

Or if your css file is not in your web server root

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/path/to/your/style.css">
```

In a general way, avoid to use relative path, excepted from specific situations. You can learn more about relative and absolute path here [Absolute and Relative URLs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676525(v=vs.85).aspx)